# Mediapipe read from numpy array

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, mediapipe

I have a requirement to read a frame output of opencv in Mediapipe. I am using Mediapipe latest version 0.9.1.0.

I am trying to seek a frame in the opencv video input and

```
import mediapipe as mp
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,10)
ret, frame = cap.read()
mp_image = mp.Image(format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8])
    2. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint16])
    3. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float32])
```

I am trying to follow the document here https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/object_detector/python#video_1

Appreciate any pointers on what I am doing wrong.

S

Comment: it is always good to check whether the frame has really been captured. After `ret, frame = cap.read()`, use `if ret: mp_image = mp.Image(format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame) else: break`

Answer (score 3):

There is probably an error in the documentation. Use image_format instead of format:

```
mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame)
```

More to the mp.Image class here: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/api/solutions/python/mp/Image

Comment: Thanks also works on mediapipe==0.10.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Mediapipe to the latest version which is **0.10.0** not 0.9.1.0
Also make sure that the returned frame in not None, as it is the case when you iterate over a video's frames in openCV.